# Automatically resolve conflict on git for given file

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have database schema file in repo with always changes. Is there a possiblity to fix conflicts with `ours` or `theirs` strategy on merge automatically?

Comment: Why does the file change all the time, and in ways that causes conflicts?

Comment: This is mysql schema file, and every rails migration causes some small diffs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a [custom merge driver](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) by adding a stanza like the following to your `.git/config`:

```
[merge "ours"]
  name = Always take our version
  driver = echo
[merge "theirs"]
  name = Always take their version
  driver = cat %B > %A
```

The merge driver accepts a number of parameters -- `%A` is "our" version of the file and `%B` is "their" version -- and is expected to leave the result of the merge in `%A`. Hence, the "our" merge driver does nothing, while the "theirs" merge driver can just copy `%B` over `%A`.

Now, tell `git` to use either the `ours` or `theirs` merge strategy for your file with a [`.gitattributes` file](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html):

```
db/schema.rb merge=theirs

# Or:

db/schema.rb merge=ours
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this file to .gitignore